# Make calls to Java code from a Smartsheet Cell and update other column cells

Tags: java, smartsheet-api

I would like to make a call from one of the Smartsheet Column Cell to a Java code running on web server (could be Servlet or a Portlet). 
The Java code will retrieve other relevant data from a data source (database) and updates the resultset information retrieved from data source into other column cells in the Smartsheet.

One immediate solution I could think of:
- Create a hyperlink pointing to Java code and add it to one of the desired Cell. 
- If the user click on the hyperlink in column cell then trigger the call to Java code and update the rest of columns (for that particular row).

I would like to know if there are other alternatives/ideas of doing it ?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution of providing a hyperlink in a cell to trigger an external script that will populate the rest of the cells in the row sounds like a viable solution.

Depending on the level of interaction you're looking for in the process, there is also the [Data Tracker project](http://www.smartsheet.com/apps/smartsheet-labs-data-tracker). Data Tracker is a Python app that runs in the command-line that uses a value in the row to find corresponding data in external systems. The app can be [configured](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker#configure-source) to query several different types of data sources, and can even be [extended](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker#create-your-own) to include other data sources that meet your needs.

This would be more of a scheduled solution, rather than an interactive solution with the user clicking the link.